# Wanting to start the ai detection software under "OnStartClick" via a start button with the webcam displaying on the top panel

Tags: python

import cv2
import numpy as np
import wx

class Main(wx.Frame):
    def **init**(self):
        wx.Frame.**init**(self,parent = None, title = "Baby Sleep Monitor", size = (700,700))
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        top = TopPanel(splitter)
        bottom = BottomPanel(splitter,top)
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(top, bottom)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(470)

class TopPanel (wx.Panel):
    def **init**(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.**init**(self,parent = parent)

class BottomPanel (wx.Panel):
    def **init**(self,parent,top):
        wx.Panel.**init**(self,parent = parent)
        self.graph = top
        self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")

```
    self.togglebuttonStart = wx.ToggleButton(self, id = -1, label = "Start", pos = (10,10))
    self.togglebuttonStart.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.OnStartClick)

    labelchannels = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Analogue Inputs", pos = (200, 20))
    self.cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, label = "A0", pos = (200, 40))
    self.cb2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, label = "A1", pos = (200, 55))
    self.cb3 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, label = "A2", pos = (200, 70))
    self.cb4 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, label = "A3", pos = (200, 85))

    self.textboxSampleTime = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "1000", pos=(200, 115), size=(50, -1))
    self.buttonSend = wx.Button(self, -1, "Send", pos=(250, 115), size=(50, -1))
    self.buttonSend.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSend)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX,self.OnChecked)

    labelMinY = wx.StaticText(self,-1, "Min Y", pos = (400,10))
    self.textboxMinYAxis = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"0",pos = (400,30))

    labelMaxY = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Max Y", pos=(400, 60))
    self.textboxMaxYAxis = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "1024", pos=(400, 80))

    self.buttonRange = wx.Button(self,-1,"Set Y Axis", pos = (400,105))
    self.buttonRange.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SetButtonRange)

def SetButtonRange(self,event):
    min = self.textboxMinYAxis.GetValue()
    max = self.textboxMaxYAxis.GetValue()
    print(max)
    print(min)
    self.graph.changeAxes(min,max)

def OnChecked(self, event):
    cb = event.GetEventObject()
    print("%s is clicked" % (cb.GetLabel()))

def OnStartClick(self,event):
    val = self.togglebuttonStart.GetValue()
    if val == True:
        self.togglebuttonStart.SetLabel("Stop")

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX

        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
        fullb_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
        left_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_profileface.xml')
        right_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_profileface.xml')
        back_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('backcascade.xml')
        while 1:
            value = self.togglebuttonStart.GetValue()
            ret, img = cap.read()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            full_body = fullb_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 2)
            for (fx, fy, fw, fh) in full_body:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (fx, fy), (fx + fw, fy + fh), (0, 255, 255), 2)

            left_face = left_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            for (x2, y2, w2, h2) in left_face:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x2, y2), (x2 + w2, y2 + h2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                roi_gray = gray[y2:y2 + h2, x2:x2 + w2]
                roi_color = img[y2:y2 + h2, x2:x2 + w2]
                cv2.putText(img, str('left face'), (x2, y2 + h2), font, 1, 255)

            back = back_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            for (x4, y4, w4, h4) in back:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x4, y4), (x4 + w4, y4 + h4), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(img, str('danger'), (x4, y4 + h4), font, 1, 255)

            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                cv2.putText(img, str('face'), (x, y + h), font, 1, 255)

                eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
                for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
                    cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cv2.imshow('img', img)
            k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if value == False:
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        self.togglebuttonStart.SetLabel("Start")

def OnSend(self, event):
    val = self.textboxSampleTime.GetValue()
    print(val)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    app = wx.App()`enter code here`
    frame = Main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

Comment: It's difficult to know what your question is here. All we see is a whole lot of code, what's your question?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am new to this forum and am unsure of how to create a more organized post. I have just created another post that is easier for people to understand.

Comment: Your other question is _much_ better and clearer. Well done!